# Changing the values in a dict, changes the values of the original returned dict

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary, object-oriented-analysis

```
def data_query(Chan, Mode, Format, Sampling, Wave_Data):
    if Mode.get_state() == 'NORM':
        if Chan.get_state() == 'CHAN1':
            wave_dict = Wave_Data.get_wave_data(1)
            if Format.get_state() == 'ASCII':
                return wave_dict
            elif Format.get_state() == 'BYTE':
                for i in range(0, len(wave_dict)):
                    wave_dict[i] = bin(int(wave_dict[i]))
                return wave_dict
```

So in the code above, the parameter 'Wave_Data' is an instance of another class which holds the value of a dict 'self.wave1' which is returned by the function 'get_wave_data'.

```
    def get_wave_data(self, channel=1):
        if channel == 1:
            return self.wave1
        elif channel == 2:
            pass
```

My problem is that in the code above when I make changes to the values in the local dict - 'wave_dict' (i.e. convert the values to binary), it also the changes the values in self.wave1. If I understand this correctly, its acting as a pointer to the self.wave1 object (which I am streaming using udp sockets via another thread) rather than a normal local variable.

Btw, the first code block is a function in the main thread and the second code block is a function in a class that is running as a daemon thread, the instance of which is also passed in the 'data_query' function.

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if I've used wrong terminology anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating an array and appending the hex(dict values) to this array, then returning the array instead of the dict.

Then I handle this on the receiving end by try-except to accept either a dict or a list:

```
        try:
            Wdata = list(Wdata_dict.values())
        except:
            Wdata = Wdata_dict
```